# Double curly braces in Bash - bad substitution

Tags: bash

This works:

`echo ${!var_pointing_to_another_var}`

This doesn't:

`echo ${!${var}_string_suffix}`

In other words, I have a variable consisting of two parts: the first part is another variable, the second part is a string suffix. Together, they form a variable that would point to another variable. But I get a bad substitution error.

Due to readability and security issues, I want to avoid the `eval` command.

Comment: You might try `zsh`; it handles more nested constructs than Bash does.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this is the only way:

```
t="${var}_string_suffix"
echo "${!t}"
```

Comment: That's correct.  The `!` indirection doesn't work on arbitrary strings - it only works on variables whose value is the exact target variable name.

Answer (score 2):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

What you probably want is an [associative array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays).

```
# The most common multi-dimensional array emulation for bash >= 4.0 is
# to use an associative array with delimiter.
typeset -A arr=([foo;bar]=test)
printf '%s\n' "${arr[$(printf '%q;%q' "$var1" "$var2")]}" # bash 4
```

Indirection using `${!var}` is less portable and not necessarily safer than `eval`. `eval` based indirection is well-understood, while bash indirect expansion can introduce obscure bugs without a solid understanding of its mechanics and careful input validation. The above wiki page provides a good introduction. "namerefs" are another workaround for bash 4.3, but they generally shouldn't be used in this way.

```
var1=foo
var2=bar
foobar=test
ref=${var1}${var2}
printf '%s\n' "${!ref}" # print test (bash-only, <= 4.3)

# Note: not a great example of nameref usage
typeset -n ref2=${var1}${var2}
printf '%s\n' "$ref2" # bash >= 4.3 / ksh93 / mksh

# Correct eval usage
if [[ $ref == [a-zA-Z_]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]) ]]; then
    eval printf '%s\\n' "\${$ref}" # POSIX
    eval printf '%s\\n' "$(printf '${%q}' "$ref")" # bash / ksh93 / zsh
fi
```